# Rendering components within other components in React

Tags: reactjs

I have a matrix component that has a 2d list of elements, and I want to render them in a table, each as a button. So, it works fine when my code is like this:

```
{Object(
     e.map(f => {
     return (
     <td>
         <button> {0} </button>
     </td>
     );
    })
 )}
```

But, when I try and render the same output in a different component, it doesn't work, and nothing renders:

```
{Object(
      e.map(f => {
      return (
      <td>
        <matrixElement/>
       </td>
       );
      })
   )}

class matrixElement extends Component {
  render() {
    return <button> {0} </button>;
  }
}
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that this is JSX, whatever you're returning there would be converted to `React.createElement(...)`. Now, in your first example you're using lowercase elements, which means `React.createElement` will try to interpret those as built-in elements (HTML elements) like `<div>`, `<span>`, `<button>`...

In your second example you're trying to render `<matrixElement>`, which means that `React.createElement()` will try to interpret this as an HTML element instead of a Component, so what you want to do is to always name your components uppercase `MatrixElement`.

tldr; React Components should always be Uppercase.

[You can read more about JSX here](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized